# How do I know $a+a+...+a$ $n$ times is $na$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

For a cardinal $a$ and a positive integer $n$

This seems almost trivial but I’m not sure how I can show it is true. Is it defined to be this way or must it be shown?

Comment: We prove it using [cardinal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_arithmetic). See e.g. Patrick Suppes, [Axiomatic set theory, (Dover, 1960)](https://books.google.it/books?id=skTCAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), page 114-on : $a + 0=a, a \cdot 1=a$. And with e.g. $2=1+1$ we have : $a \cdot 2= a \cdot (1+1)=a + a$. Then use induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a consequence of [distrbutive law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) that is since

$$n=\overbrace{1+1+\ldots+1}^{\text{n times}}$$

then

$$a \cdot n=a\cdot (1+1+\ldots+1)=\overbrace{a+a+\ldots+a}^{\text{n times}}$$

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Couldn’t see how to implement this law. I used $a+a+...+a = a*1+a*1+ ... +a*1=a(1+1+...+1)=an=na$ To add an extra step to make it even more clear using the laws. Thanks.

Comment: @Anteater23 You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 0):

Proof by induction:
For $n=1: na=a$ checks

Assume $n=k hold: a+a+a...a\ k\ times =ka$

So for $n=k+1: a+a+a..a\ k+1\ times=(k+1)$

$a+a+a...k+1\ times=a+a+a...a\ k\ times + a =ka + a =(k+1)a$

Therefore $a+a+a...a\ n\ times$ hold true.

**Hence Proved**